# How can I strip some numbers on a url for 301 redirection

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all the request from the url:

http://www.example.com/the-news/category/12345-name-of-post

to

http://www.example.com/name-of-post

How can I strip the numbers and the hyphen?

I know how to do the redirection, but don't know how to strip the numbers and the hyphen.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this, I used:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/the-news/(.*)/\d{1,6}-(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$2
```

The \d{1,6} part is for recognizing numbers from 1 to 6 digits.